# how to give dynamic latitdute & longitude values in google map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API.Here i am giving static latitdute & longitude means it is working fine.but my requirement is In AJAX response i am passing latitdute & longitude values,instead of static latitdute & longitude values i want to give my dynamic latitdute & longitude values(coming from my json response).

```js
function initMap(lat,long) {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: long
    } // Starting Point Marathahalli
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;

  /* configure waypoints */
  var waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
    location: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: long
    }, // HAL
    stopover: true
  }, {
    location: {
      lat:lat,
      lng:long
    },
    stopover: true
  });

  directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: long
    }, // Haight.
    destination: {
      lat:lat,
      lng: long
    }, // Ending Point Shivaji Nagar.
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
    waypoints: waypts
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Travel modes in directions</title>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="testForm">

    <select name="tripId">
  <option value="">Select trip</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>

    <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
  </form><br></br>

  <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code that I tried with `onclick` event:

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url :"getLatLan.php",
         data : $('#testForm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(res);
if(res['status']=='success'){
      var position=res.data;
  for (var i=0; i<position.length; i++)
  {
  initMap(position[i].latitude,position[i].longitude);
    }


                  }
           },
         error:function(exception){
         alert('Exeption:'+exception);
        }
        });

});
```

I *am* getting a response in AJAX (`console.log(res);`):

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "",
        "pickUpLongitude": "",
        "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
        "driverId": "G2E100",
        "routeId": "1",
        "tripDate": "2017-08-01 15:45:55",
        "startTime": "15:45:55",
        "endTime": "14:48:55",
        "shiftId": "1",
        "tripStatus": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "empId": "G2E201",
        "callStartTime": "",
        "callEndTime": "",
        "cabReachingTime": "",
        "pickupTime": "15:50:02",
        "dropTime": "",
        "dropStatus": "0",
        "otp": "421283",
        "pickupotpStatus": "1",
        "empPresentStatus": "0",
        "latitdute": "12.9583665",
        "longitude": "77.6635659"
    },
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "",
        "pickUpLongitude": "",
        "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
        "driverId": "G2E100",
        "routeId": "1",
        "tripDate": "2017-08-01 15:45:55",
        "startTime": "15:45:55",
        "endTime": "14:48:55",
        "shiftId": "1",
        "tripStatus": "0",
        "id": "2",
        "empId": "G2E200",
        "callStartTime": "",
        "callEndTime": "",
        "cabReachingTime": "",
        "pickupTime": "",
        "dropTime": "",
        "dropStatus": "0",
        "otp": "",
        "pickupotpStatus": "0",
        "empPresentStatus": "0",
        "latitdute": "12.9630167",
        "longitude": "77.6268656"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You need to use the data from the AJAX success function in `initMap`

Comment: From my json response latitude and longitude values i am getting , i want to pass this value to initMap(), i terid like this var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(res);
      $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
                    var latitdute = value.latitdute;
                    var longitude = value.longitude;
       if(res['status']=='success'){
         initMap(latitdute,longitude);
       }
      });
But first time only loop is runing,next time i am getting error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**.

Comment: you just want to nake dynamic your waypoints through ajax or also origin and destination in directionsService.route({ ? secondly this map show on your form sumit? or you are showing default one also?

Answer (score 0):

Here is My code to show Map On click.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>map</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDDsuLejDmtPUTbx6AbVuuH6C2VjZILXnM&libraries=places"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">



    </script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
var centreGot = false;

  var map; // Global declaration of the map
  var lat_longs_map = new Array();
  var markers_map = new Array();
        var iw_map;

  iw_map = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



     function tester(lat,long) {


    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
 myOptions);

    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long));
      }, function() { alert("Unable to get your current position. Please try again. Geolocation service failed."); });
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    }else{
      alert('Your browser does not support geolocation.');
    }
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function(event) {
      if (!centreGot) {
 var mapCentre = map.getCenter();
 marker_0.setOptions({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long) 
 });
}
   centreGot = true;
    });

  var markerOptions = {
    map: map    
  };
  marker_0 = createMarker_map(markerOptions);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load");

  }


function createMarker_map(markerOptions) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  markers_map.push(marker);
  lat_longs_map.push(marker.getPosition());
  return marker;

}




  </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;">
  <button onclick="tester(12.9630167,77.6268656);">My Position</button> </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

In your case, you can call the same function on ajax success like

```
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:your url,
    data:your data,
    success:function(res){
     var position=res.data;
    for (var i=0; i<position.length; i++)
{
   tester(position[i].latitude,position[i].longitude);
 }

    }
});
```

Hopefully, it works.

Comment: I am busy at the moment I will do later.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your point what you want to show, you have two objects in your res.data each one has pick_up coordinates and simple coordinates. You can show only one at time and in that case, you must have pick_up coordinates.I did some changes look at it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
</script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','#btn-submit',function(e){



e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url :"getLatLan.php",
     data : $('#testForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//your_res is equal to var res you can delete that.
            var your_res={
 "status": "success",
 "count": 2,
 "data": [
{
    "tripId": "1",
    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9630167",
    "pickUpLongitude": "77.6268656",
    "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
    "driverId": "G2E100",
    "routeId": "1",
    "tripDate": "2017-08-01 15:45:55",
    "startTime": "15:45:55",
    "endTime": "14:48:55",
    "shiftId": "1",
    "tripStatus": "0",
    "id": "1",
    "empId": "G2E201",
    "callStartTime": "",
    "callEndTime": "",
    "cabReachingTime": "",
    "pickupTime": "15:50:02",
    "dropTime": "",
    "dropStatus": "0",
    "otp": "421283",
    "pickupotpStatus": "1",
    "empPresentStatus": "0",
    "latitdute": "12.9583665",
    "longitude": "77.6635659"
},
{
    "tripId": "1",
    "pickUpLatitidute": "",
    "pickUpLongitude": "",
    "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
    "driverId": "G2E100",
    "routeId": "1",
    "tripDate": "2017-08-01 15:45:55",
    "startTime": "15:45:55",
    "endTime": "14:48:55",
    "shiftId": "1",
    "tripStatus": "0",
    "id": "2",
    "empId": "G2E200",
    "callStartTime": "",
    "callEndTime": "",
    "cabReachingTime": "",
    "pickupTime": "",
    "dropTime": "",
    "dropStatus": "0",
    "otp": "",
    "pickupotpStatus": "0",
    "empPresentStatus": "0",
    "latitdute": "12.9630167",
    "longitude": "77.6268656"
 }
 ]
 };
 var myobject=your_res.data;
 for(var i=0; i<1; i++)
  {
  //alert(myobject[i].latitdute+'-'+myobject[i].longitude);
 $lati=parseFloat(myobject[i].latitdute);
 $long=parseFloat(myobject[i].longitude);
 $pic_lati=parseFloat(myobject[i].pickUpLatitidute);
$pic_long=parseFloat(myobject[i].pickUpLongitude);
 //alert($lati);
  initMap();
  }
        //console.log(res);
  if(res['status']=='success'){
                   initMap();
              }
       },
     error:function(exception){
     alert('Exeption:'+exception);
    }
    });

   });
 </script>
<script>

 function initMap() {
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: {
  lat:12.9583665,
  lng:77.6635659
  } // Starting Point Marathahalli
 });
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

 calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;

/* configure waypoints */
// var waypts = [];
// waypts.push({
//   location: {
//     lat: 12.9583662,
//     lng: 77.6635653
//   }, // HAL
//   stopover: true
// }, {
//   location: {
//     lat: 12.9630164,
//     lng: 77.6268655
//   },
//   stopover: true
// });

directionsService.route({

  origin: {
  lat:$lati,
  lng:$long
  }, // Haight.
  destination: {
  lat:$pic_lati,
  lng:$pic_long
  }, // Ending Point Shivaji Nagar.
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
  //waypoints: waypts
 }, function(response, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
   directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  console.log(response);
   } else {
  window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
 });
 }
 </script>
<style>
#map {
height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

 html,
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
left: 25%;
z-index: 5;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #999;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
 line-height: 30px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Travel modes in directions</title>


</head>
<body>
 <form id="testForm">

   <select name="tripId">
    <option value="">Select trip</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>

   <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
  </form><br></br>

   <div id="floating-panel">
  <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
    <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```